# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, http

I'm trying to get currency conversion data from an API ("https://api.exchangerate.host/latest").

The above error in the title is shown on the screen as a text.

I'm trying to get this message as the output.

"msg":"If you or your company use this project or like what we doing, please consider backing us so we can continue maintaining and evolving this project."

Later the individual currency rates.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.exchangerate.host/latest'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String msg;

  Album({
    required this.msg,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      msg: json['msg'],
    );
  }
}

class CurrencyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrencyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CurrencyPageState createState() => _CurrencyPageState();
}

class _CurrencyPageState extends State<CurrencyPage> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.msg);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: most likely it is paid and you do not have access

Comment: @novol When you enter the URL on a browser you get the data. doesn't that mean it's free?

Comment: my mistake, show plz what are you get from `response.body`

Comment: @novol ```type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'``` This error is shown on screen

Comment: i asked response, not error, i answer below and tested - it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the model incorrectly.
change `return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));` to `return jsonDecode(response.body);` and get response data like `snapshot.data!['motd']`

code:

```
Future<dynamic> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.exchangerate.host/latest'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    print(jsonDecode(response.body));
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String msg;

  Album({
    required this.msg,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      msg: json['msg'],
    );
  }
}

class CurrencyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrencyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CurrencyPageState createState() => _CurrencyPageState();
}

class _CurrencyPageState extends State<CurrencyPage> {
  late dynamic futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!['motd']['msg']);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`msg` key is inside `motd` object in response. Therefore replace `fetchAlbum` with this:

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.exchangerate.host/latest'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
    return Album.fromJson(body["motd"]);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```